# Neal Koblitz used this limit in his calculation of $\zeta(2k)$

Tags: real-analysis

In the book "p-adic numbers, p-adic analysis and Zeta-functions", Neal Koblitz used this limit to prove Euler's sine formula: $\sin(\pi x)=\pi x\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2})$:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \prod_{r=1}^{k}\frac{1-\sin^2(x\pi/(2k+1))/\sin^2(r\pi/(2k+1))}{1-x^2/r^2}=1$$ since he proved that $\lim_{k\to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^{k}(1-\frac{\sin^2(x\pi/(2k+1)}{\sin^2(r\pi/(2k+1)})=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$.
Can you help me to prove the limit?

Comment: How did he show the second limit with the $\sin(\pi x) / (\pi x)$?

Comment: The claimed that $\sin(nx)/n\sin(x)$ is a polynomial $P(\sin(x))$ with rational coefficients of degree $2k$ with $n=2k+1$. Notice that it has $2k$ zeros $\pm i\pi/n$ for $i=1,2,\dots,k$ then $P(y)$ must have its $2k$ zeros $\pm \sin (i\pi/n)$. Thus $$\frac{\sin \pi x}{n\sin x}=\prod_{r=1}^{k}(1-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(\pi r/n)})$$ He then just replace $x$ by $\pi x/n$ and take limit $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding with Taylor series $\sin(X) = X(1 + O(X^2))$, we have
$$ \sin^2(x\pi/(2k+1)) = (x\pi/(2k+1))^2 (1+O(1/k^2)) ,$$
$$ \sin^2(r\pi/(2k+1)) = (r\pi/(2k+1))^2 (1+O(r^2/k^2)) ,$$
so
\begin{align} 1-\frac{\sin^2(x\pi/(2k+1))}{\sin^2(r\pi/(2k+1))} 
&= 1-\frac{(x\pi/(2k+1))^2}{(r\pi/(2k+1))^2} (1 + O(r^2/k^2)) 
\\&= 1-\frac{(x\pi/(2k+1))^2}{(r\pi/(2k+1))^2} + O(1/k^2) 
\\&= (1-x^2/r^2)(1 + O(1/k^2)) \end{align}
where the implied constants in the "big-Oh"s are allowed to depend upon $x$.  But
$$ \log \left(\prod_{r=1}^k (1 + O(1/k^2))\right) = \sum_{r=1}^k O(1/k^2) = O(1/k) \to 0 $$
as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Excuse me sir, it should be $\frac{1}{1+O(r^2/k^2)}$ in your second step, doesn't it?

Comment: $1/(1+O(r^2/k^2)) = (1+O(r^2/k^2))$, because $1/(1+x) \approx 1-x = 1+O(x)$.